# How could I remove all directories except 10 recent with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I have the following folders in my base `/var/www/.versions` directory:

```
1435773881 Jul  1 21:04
1435774663 Jul  2 21:17
1435774856 Jul  3 21:20
1435775432 Jul  4 21:56
```

How could I remove all directories except most 10 recent with bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, I believe?

```
rm -r $(ls -td /var/www/.versions/*/ | tac | head -n-10)
```

The idea: list (with `ls`) only directories ( that's the `-d /var/www/.versions/*/`) sorted by time with `-t` (oldest will be shown last).

Then, reverse the output using [`tac`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tac.htm) so the oldest directories are on top.

And then show them all except the last 10 lines with [`head`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uhead.htm) and a negative argument to `-n`

Please, test with non-vital directories first **;-)** You can change the `rm -r` by `echo` to see what would be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how many will be removed if `/var/www/.versions` directory contains less than 10 folders?

Comment: None. The `head` command will output an empty string and `rm` will error out with an `rm: missing operand`

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped **:-)** But, please, make sure you test with non-critical data first!!! **:-D :-D**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-rt` option in `ls` for listing in reverse order of time.

```
rm -r $(ls -trd /var/www/.versions/*/ | head -n -10)
```

Also, be sure of you put `/` in the end of `/var/www/.versions/*/` and that all directory names do not start with `.`